# Convert List<Students> to Map<K, List<V>>

Tags: java, java-8

My Student class has only three attributes - age, sex and name.
I have a Map like `Map<String, Student>` where key is an UUID string that acts as identifier for the student.

Now i want to convert this Map to another map of pattern - `Map<String,List<String>>`. In this map, key can be sex of the student and value would be list of UUIDs corresponding to that sex.

I can achieve this using pre-Java8 syntax, but i am trying to do this by Java8 stream API and lambda expressions. Please help with this.

What I have tried - 
`Map<String, Student> map;
map.entrySet().stream().collect(e ->  e.getValue().getSex(), ???how to get list of keys here???)`

I am able to set the key of the target map correctly,  but i am struggling to set the value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's not working?

Comment: Those who are downvoting, please provide me a solution as well. Just a downvote doesn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(entry -> entry.getValue().getSex(),
                    Collectors.mapping(entry -> entry.getKey(), Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: This works. Thanks.